# Where to store Twitter credentials in Shiny Application?

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth, shiny, rstudio

I'm writing a Shiny application that connects with Twitter. The problem is I want to view the application source code below the page. so, what's the best secure method to store twitter credentials?
an example would be much appreciated

Comment: Store them in a read-only file that can only be read by the process owner of the shiny app and store that file outside the shiny directory (in the event there's ever a directory traversal bug that could make them disclosable).

Comment: @hrbrmstr thank you. this gave me a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already completed the twitter authentication, there are quite a few responses to look at. A good guide can be found here:

http://blog.credera.com/business-intelligence/twitter-analytics-using-r-part-1-extract-tweets/

Once authentication has been completed you need to save the authorisation.

```
cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey='yourkey',
  consumerSecret='yoursecret',
  requestURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
  accessURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
  authURL='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')
```

Which should be authenticated:

```
cred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
```

This then needs to be saved to a directory.

```
save(cred, "twitter.authentication")
```

Then in the shiny server.R file you will need to load this file, and register it before making use of the twitteR functionality in the shiny app.

```
load("twitter.authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
```

Since this is the only code that will be shared/displayed your credentials should be secure.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used setup_twitter_oauth() before, but this seems like a good idea